# Linear programming and solutions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

So I have a question about LP problems. If one knows that the LP problem for a given objective function has an feasibel x which determines the best outcome of the objective function given a set of constraints, is it then true that the negative of the function also must have such an x value given that we have the same constraints?

Comment: short answer: yes.

Comment: @PufferFish46 Do you maximize (z,-z?) or do you minimize (z,-z?)?

Comment: @PufferFish46 If you maximize $z$ the feasible solution is unbounded. If you maximize $-z$ (=minimizing $z$) then you get an optimal solution.

Comment: @PufferFish46 This is right. But you probably know the strong duality theorem: If the primal has an optimal solution, then the dual has the same optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, as exemplified by the simplest LP having an optimal solution.

minimize $x$ subject to $x \ge 0$ has optimal solution $x = 0$.

minimize $-x$ subject to $x \ge 0$ is unbounded, i.e., optimal objective value = $-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)